# I m not able to submit form, already exist or not in cakephp using ajax

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am checking user already exit using ajax in cakephp. everything is right, i got response ok

but if user is not exit then i am not able to submit form following is my code:- problem is in else part, how to submit form.

```
function checku(email) {
        var email=document.getElementById("check").value;

        var data='';
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>users/alreadyexist/'+email,    
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { 
            var response=html;          
            if(response=="ok")
            {
             alert('The user is already Exist');

            }
            else
            {

            alert("else");

            }

        }

        });
    return false;

}
```

And this following is button , I m calling function :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->submit('ssad.png',array('onclick'=>'return checku();'));?>
```

Comment: you can directly return from condition after alert

Comment: i did it but if i remove return false from outermost function does not work

Answer (score 0):

```
return false; put this under the `alert('The user is already Exist');`
```

In else case just do `return true;`

```
if(response=="ok")
{
    alert('The user is already Exist');
    return false;
}
else
{    
    alert("else");
    return true;
}
```

remove the outermost return false.

It will work even if you dont remove the outermost return false; though.

Comment: How to put return under the alert?

Comment: function checku(email) {
        var email=document.getElementById("check").value;

        var data='';
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>users/alreadyexist/'+email,    
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,     
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { 
            var response=html;          
            if(response=="ok")
            {
             alert('The user is already Exist');
return true;
            }
            else
            {

            alert("else");
return false;
            }

        }

        });
  

}

Comment: if i m doing this return in if and else part it sumbits form in both cases

Comment: How to put return under the alert? . i dont know

Comment: What do you mean how to put it under alert?You just have to cut it from where it is right now and just paste it under that.Check edits in my answer.

Comment: If i remove return false from end of javascript then it submits form. and put return false and true in case of if and else

Comment: Ok dont remove it.Just add the return statements as I have made in my answer.Check the answer,I have posted some code in it.

Comment: function checku(email) {
  var email=document.getElementById("check").value;
  
  var data='';
  $.ajax({ 
   url: '<?php echo BASE_PATH;?>users/alreadyexist/'+email, 
   type: 'POST',
   data: data,  
   cache: false,
   success: function (html) { 
   var response=html;   
   if(response=="ok")
   {
    alert('The user is already Exist');
   
     return true;
   }
   else
   {
   
   alert("else");
   document.form1.submit();
     return false;
   }
   
   
  }
   
  });
 return false;

}

Comment: if(response=="ok") { alert('The user is already Exist'); return false; } else {

            alert("else");
            return true;
            }
remove the outermost return false. if i do so it is also not working

Comment: Thanks to all. I have done it. I put the following code $('#Form').submit(); in else part, now i am able to submit the form. I am very thankful to all of your support .